# sql multiple filter all conditions in a group

Tags: sql, filter

I have a table with 3 fields:

```
id       order        date

1        1            null
1        2            not null
1        3            null
2        1            null
2        2            null
2        3            null
2        4            not null
3        1            null
```

I need the "id" in which:

- ALL the "order" in (1,2,3)

and

- ALL the "date" is null (so it is id 2)

I've tried as follows:

`where order in (1,2,3) and date is null`

but it returns both id 2 and id 1 (I'm expecting id 2 only).

Thanks for helps.

Comment: Why don't you expect id 3? It has order 1, which is in (1,2,3), and date is `null`

Comment: Id 2 has the invalid orderid 4, and you still want it?

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS. Which is yours? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: On a sidenote: Even for an example it's a bad idea to name a column ID, when it's not the table's unique ID.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner , how can I understand my DMBS ( I am using TOAD editor) if you can help me about it I will write down. thank you.

Comment: Well, usually one knows what database system one is working with. TOAD sounds like Oracle. Try `select * from v$version`. Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

ID 3 should be also included. It satisfies your condition.

```
SELECT distinct id
FROM tab1 aa
WHERE aa.order IN (1, 2, 3) AND aa.data IS NULL
      AND NOT exists(SELECT 1
                     FROM tab1 bb
                     WHERE ((bb.order IN (1, 2, 3) AND bb.data IS NOT NULL) 
OR
(bb.order NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND bb.data IS NULL))
                           AND aa.id = bb.id);
```

If you don't want ID 2 cause it has order in ID 4, then relax the last condition in:

```
bb.order NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
```

without the check in the date.

If with 
ALL the "order" in (1,2,3)
you mean that there should be an order for 1, an order for 2 and an order for 3, then you should add and exists in the query to check this, like

```
and exists (select 1 form tab1 cc where aa.id = cc.id and cc.order = 1 and cc.data is not null)
```

and so on.

Comment: `Distinct` is not function, it's a part of `select distinct` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove the redundant parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply do 'SELECT DISTINCT id ...`.

Comment: @jarlh why do you say redundant parentheses? it is like:
( (A and B) OR (C and D)) condition, I can't delete parentheses unless changing the meaning of the filter. I updated the distinct, thanks for the hint. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6af0a9/11

Comment: Sorry, you had `SELECT distinct (id)` - where the parentheses are redundant. I wasn't talking about the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly interpreted your question, the following SQL does the work.

It returns `id` values of records for which all *order* who have `1`, `2` or `3` value have `null` value for the *date* field:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM t
WHERE
    order IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    date IS NULL AND
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM t
        WHERE
            order IN (1, 2, 3) AND
            date IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: `Distinct` is not function, it's a part of `select distinct` and works on the whole selected rows. Remove the redundant parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. simply do 'SELECT DISTINCT id ...`.

Comment: @jarlh: You're right. I've updated the answer, thanks for suggestion

Comment: it does not work, it also brings other nulls , ı just want the one which all 1,2,3 are null , not one by one

Comment: @determinator: I've updated the answer, please check if it works

Comment: @determinator: If my answer solved the problem, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/386306)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what database are you using so I tried to right a query that should work with most. Have a look:

```
select * from
(select 
   id,
   SUM(case
      when [order] = 1 and [date] is  null then 1
      when [order] = 2 and [date] is  null then 1
      when [order] = 3 and [date] is  null then 1
      else 0
   end) score
from test
group by id) scores
where score = 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e4334/9

Answer (score 0):

You want a result per ID, so `GROUP BY` it. You are only interested in  order 1, 2, and 3, so use a `WHERE` clause. You only want IDs with all three orders and no date set. You can check this after aggregation in the `HAVING` clause.

```
select id
from mytable
where "order" in (1,2,3)
group by id
having count(*) = 3 -- all three IDs
and count("date") = 0; -- no non-null date
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/SEE91944

(I surmise the table's unique key is `id` + `order`. Otherwise you'd have to `COUNT(DISTINCT "order")` and maybe to check null dates differently. As both `order` and `date` are SQL words, I am using quotes on them. You should avoid such names.)

Comment: What does that mean? What is a "smaller group"? For your sample data it retrives ID 2, which is exactly what you asked for. Look at my query. Understand it. How is it different from what you want? Is `id` + `order` unique in the table? If not, how shall this influence the results?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but none of above solved my question.

I solved it using "where not exists" (excluding the unwanted)

thanks to you all for your efforts.